# Not able to inject repository in viewmodel which have fragmentComponent scope

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I'm using bottom navigation with 4 tabs. I want to load **FragmentA** in tab 1 with different instance and load same fragment(**FragmentA**) in tab2 with different instance and different viewModel instance. I'm using Hilt to inject repositories into viewmodel.

Now I'm facing one issue which is **FragmentA** is loading in tab 1&2  with same instance.

1. SingleComponent will not work here.
2. ActivityComponent also won't work because it will create single instance across the activity. tab1 and tab2  will open in same activity.

I tried with FragmentComponent and not able to inject repositories into ViewModel.

I'm expecting FragmentComponent repositories inject into viewmodel without any issues or any other better solution ?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
object ProductUseCaseModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideGetProductUseCase(
        productRepository: ProductRepository
    ): GetProductUseCase {
        return GetProductUseCaseDefault(productRepository)
    }
 }




@HiltViewModel
Class ProductViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getProductUseCase: GetProductUseCase): ViewModel{
}



@AndroidEntryPoint
Class ProductFragment : Fragment {
  private val viewModel : ProductViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here, the code you define the Fragment, the ViewModel, and the Module to inject the repository

Comment: Your `ProductFragment` inherits from `AppCompactActivity` seems weird, is this your current code? So your problem is that the `ProductViewModel`  gets the same `GetProductUseCase` instance on every Fragment object right?

Comment: `Fragment`  should extend from `Fragment` not from `AppCompactActivity`

Comment: The question is still not clear the problem you meet. You get the same `ViewModel` or the same `GetProductUseCase`, or the same `ProductRepository` instance and want to avoid that?

Comment: `InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)` doesn't mean that all the fragments get the same instance, it just tells Hilt that you want your dependencies to be used in any Fragment in the code, whenever it's used, a new instance is created. So there must be something wrong not because of `InstallIn` annotation

Comment: @KamalNayan Sorry by mistake i have added extends AppCompactActivity here but its actually extend Fragment only.

Comment: @TamHuynh : Firstly, Inject GetProductUseCase in ViewModel is giving compile time issue.  As per the documentation we can't inject fragmentComponent usecases in ViewModel

Comment: @Ramakrishna check this post for scope related info https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/scoping-in-android-and-hilt-c2e5222317c0

Comment: @KamalNayan I have seen this doc. Nothing related to FragmentComponent.

Comment: @TamHuynh  GetProductUseCase should return different instance every time.

Comment: If you are not using `Singleton` and `SingletonComponent` for module then it will provide you new instance every time

Comment: @KamalNayan : I'm not using SingletonComponent. I'm using FragmentComponent for module and its not injecting in ViewModel.

Comment: So you want to achieve that every time you get a new instance of usecase?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256389/discussion-between-ramakrishna-and-kamal-nayan).

Comment: Yes @Kamal Nayan. I need new instance every time and that usecase has to inject in ViewModel without any issue.

Comment: The InstallIn component doesn't matter, you can install in `SingletonComponent` and your Provide dependency still created new object everytime, it just tells Hilt where to find your dependency objects, unless you mark your Provide with `@Singleton`. So keep it `SingletonComponent` or `ViewModelComponent` and forget it. This case is weird, how do you know it return the same instance? Did you place breakpoint at the `init` of `GetProductUseCaseDefault` to see how many times it is created?

Answer (score 0):

I have used ViewModelComponent and ViewModelScoped to the function and it creates new instances in different tabs.

Working code:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object ProductUseCaseModule {

    @ViewModelScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideGetProductUseCase(
        productRepository: ProductRepository
    ): GetProductUseCase {
        return GetProductUseCaseDefault(productRepository)
    }

 }
```